# How to access fields (extension) value from a service task

Tags: activiti

I'm trying to create a process where I'm using an `JavaDelegate` task. I've to pass some additional static values to the task instance (like a mail template name). I'm trying to pass it through the `field` extension, but I'm unable to access it from task class.

How can I access a `field` value from a `JavaDelegate` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fields` extension is supported only for `Java Class` task, not for `Delegate Expression`.

Refer [documentation](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#serviceTaskFieldInjection).